# CSS Asset Overflowing With Hidden Set

Tags: html, css, overflow

Unique question here. I'm using these CSS Lasers for a Night-Club website: https://codepen.io/jefferymills/pen/xpmDK

Code because it's required even though on CodePen

HTML

```
<div class="laser-beam"></div>
<div class="laser-beam red"></div>
<div class="laser-beam purple"></div>
<div class="laser-beam green"></div>
```

CSS

```
html {
  background: #222;
}

.laser-beam {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 3px;
  height: 500%;
  background: rgba(99, 195, 231, 0.6);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px #63c3e7;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px #63c3e7;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px #63c3e7;
  -moz-transform-origin: 0 100%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 0 100%;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 100%;
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
  -webkit-animation: laser 7s infinite;
}
.laser-beam.red {
  -webkit-animation: laser 7.5s infinite;
  background: rgba(236, 19, 65, 0.6);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px #ec1341;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px #ec1341;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px #ec1341;
}
.laser-beam.purple {
  -webkit-animation: laser 7.3s infinite;
  background: rgba(204, 102, 255, 0.6);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px #cc66ff;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px #cc66ff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px #cc66ff;
}
.laser-beam.green {
  -webkit-animation: laser 7.7s infinite;
  background: rgba(86, 212, 69, 0.6);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px #56d445;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px #56d445;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px #56d445;
}

@-webkit-keyframes laser {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-75deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-75deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-75deg);
    transform: rotate(-75deg);
  }
  50% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(75deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(75deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(75deg);
    transform: rotate(75deg);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-75deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-75deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-75deg);
    transform: rotate(-75deg);
  }
}
```

I can't get the lasers to not create an overflow-x, is there any reason for this? I want them to cover the whole page but not to create a scrollbar

I've tried adding them into a div and adding overflow:hidden; to the styling, as well as height:100%; width:100%; and I've also tried setting it in the lasers CSS, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Thanks!

Zach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap them in a div. Make that div absolute to the body.

```
<div class="hide-overflow">
<div class="laser-beam"></div>
<div class="laser-beam red"></div>
<div class="laser-beam purple"></div>
<div class="laser-beam green"></div>
</div>

.hide-overflow {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Or you can just set the body overflow

```
body {
overflow: hidden;
}
```